# Visual Studio 2019 JSX closing tag autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2019

I am attempting to use the new Visual Studio 2019 on a Typescript React project and came across an issue with autocomplete when adding a closing html tag, for some reason VS wants to remove the `\` when selecting the closing tag from the autocomplete context menu.

For example when entering a `<div>` then start typing the `</div>` if you select the div from the context menu it will remove the closing slash and leave you with `<div><div>`

It looks like there have been a few tickets made:

[Closing TAG when editing JSX or TSX file](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/596686/closing-tag-when-editing-jsx-or-tsx-file.html?inRegister=true)

[React (jsx/tsx) tags auto-close does not work](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/242555/react-jsxtsx-tags-auto-close-does-not-work.html)

I can not find any work arounds and MS doesn't seem to be too concerned about it, I did manage to stop the behavior for one session by disabling some of the formatting plugins but as soon as VS was restarted the behavior came back even though the plugins were disabled. Has anyone found a work around for this?

Visual Studio 2017 seems to work just fine so I have been using that for now but would like to get up to date.

### Update

---

It looks like the feature isn't totally broken, I did notice that if you cancel (Escape) out of the initial context menu that displays the list of opening tags then start entering the closing tag the correct context menu is displayed.

Or if you simply escape out of the context menu after entering `</` and type `CTRL + Space` it will enter the closing tag.

Is there a setting that I am missing?